# Bash or sh cannot execute any binary files

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, homebrew, macports

While I am able to execute binaries, when the terminal is open, if I type:

```
/bin/bash make
```

or

```
/bin/sh ls
```

I get:
    /usr/bin/make: /usr/bin/make: cannot execute binary file

Why is that? I am on `Mavericks`, and I have installed the latest `Command Line Tools` of XCode.

I want to use bash to execute make, because I want to setup external build tools for `AppCode`.

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call `/bin/bash` with only one argument, you can only run *scripts*. Not binaries. This has nothing to do with the tools you installed, it's just the behavior described in the man page.

`/bin/bash -c ls` should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have another question. When I execute `/bin/bash` the PATH env. var is not set. Are there any CLA for `bash` to run my `.profile` file?

Comment: @Paschalis The `-l` argument will make the shell a "login" shell, meaning it will execute your `.profile`/`.bash_profile`/etc.

Comment: Hmm, it didn't worked, but I found a workaround for my case! THANKS!

Comment: @Paschalis It works for me, but as a more general way, the `--init-file` option will allow you to specify a file to run at startup.

Comment: Note that if you have Terminal open, you are already running bash (unless you changed your default shell). Thus, all you have to do to have bash run ls is type the command `ls`. When you type `/bin/bash -c ls`, that tells bash to run *another* instance of bash, and have *that* instance run ls. I can't think of a reason to bother with that second bash instance...

Comment: Yes, I know Gordon! I only wanted to type C, in a decent IDE! Not in Eclipse, not in XCode, and not in gedit! :) (please don't reply with vi, etc!)